# What are the translations for these "cogito ergo sum" variations?

Tags: sentence-translation

I'm trying to find reasonable translations for the following:

- I think, therefore I evolve
- I think, therefore I progress

Ideally, I'm looking for something short starting with "cogito ergo" but I don't know if that applies in these cases, or if I'm trying to use the wrong English equivalents for what I'm trying to say.

Are there any other synonyms (such as "improve") that could be elegantly translated and make grammatical sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need are the verb forms "I evolve" and "I progress".
Fortunately, many [Latin dictionaries](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/79) list verbs in this particular form.
I suggest taking a look at [*procedo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=procedo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (roughly "to go forward") and [*melioresco*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=melioresco&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (roughly "to become better").
If they don't look appropriate, please specify what is wrong.

If the meanings of these verbs are close enough to what you want, I suggest

> *Cogito, ergo procedo.* — I think, therefore I progress.
>   *Cogito, ergo melioresco.* — I think, therefore I improve.

There is also the verb [*evolvo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=evolvo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), but id doesn't really mean "evolve" in Latin.
The origin of the word "progress" is [*progredior*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=progredior&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), and that is indeed a possible choice.
The English verb comes from the past participle *progressus*, which also has the form *progresso*, but it doesn't mean "I progress".
The analogy between the different forms is nicer for a non-deponent verb (one ending in *-o* rather than *-or*), but that is only a matter of aesthetics.